# Zooming out on Leaflet.js with L.CRS.Simple does not load tiles properly

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaflet 0.7.2 to render tiles created with tileup from a large image (not a map) with the L.CRS.Simple projection.

I have tiles for zoom levels 17-20. Tiles display correctly at zoom levels 17 and 18. At 19 I see scaled tiles from zoom level 18. Zoom level 20 renders a blank map.

Map options:

```
{
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  center: [w / 2, h / 2],
  zoom: 17,
  minZoom: 18,
  maxZoom: 20,
  continuousWorld: true,
  layers: [
    L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/t_{x}_{y}.png')
  ]
}
```

I've tried with and without `continuousWorld` and `maxNativeZoom`.

I see 404 errors for some tiles. These are outside the provided world.

Comment: I worked around this by setting `maxZoom` to 18 and renaming the tiles to appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat counterintuitively, maxZoom on map does not propagate to layers, so your layer is keeping the default value of 18. Just try adding maxZoom to your tileLayer as well:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  center: [w / 2, h / 2],
  zoom: 17,
  minZoom: 18,
  maxZoom: 20,
  continuousWorld: true
  layers: [
    L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/t_{x}_{y}.png', {maxZoom: 20})
  ]
});
```